# Traefik not registering labels of docker-compose file

Tags: docker, traefik

This is the configuration code I have to run pihole and pihole-exporter, I used `docker-compose up -d` to run these containers. I do not know why labels do not get picked up by the Traefik, so pihole.home.local is never registered! I have been reading docs in Traefik, what might I be doing wrong?

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 

version: '3.7'

services:
  pihole:
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    hostname: "pihole"
    user: "root:root"
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "8085:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /etc/pihole:/etc/pihole
      - "/home/ansible/stacks/lighttpd/external.conf:/etc/lighttpd/external.conf"
      - dnsmasq:/etc/dnsmasq.d
    environment:
      - "TZ=China/Beijing"
      - "DNS1=1.1.1.1"
      - "DNS2=8.8.4.4"
      - "REV_SERVER=true"
      - "REV_SERVER_CIDR=192.168.1.0/24" #Update these fields to match your environment
      - "REV_SERVER_TARGET=192.168.1.1"
      - "REV_SERVER_DOMAIN=home.local"
      - "WEBPASSWORD=secret"
    cap_add:
        - SYS_PTRACE
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.rule=Host(`pihole.home.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.add-admin-prefix.addprefix.prefix=/admin"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.middlewares=add-admin-prefix@docker"
      - "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.service=pihole-http-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole-http-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.http.services.pihole-http-svc.loadbalancer.passhostheader=true"

  pihole_exporter:
    image: ekofr/pihole-exporter:latest
    hostname: pihole_exporter
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    command: "./pihole-exporter -pihole_hostname pihole -pihole_password secret"
    environment:
      - "PIHOLE_PORT=80"
      - "PIHOLE_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "PIHOLE_API_TOKEN=token_is_put_here"
      - "INTERVAL=30s"
      - "PORT=9617"
    ports:
      - target: 9617
        published: 9617
        mode: host
   

volumes:
  dnsmasq:

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

pihole works fine, I have  exposed the port 80 via  8085 just to be able to launch the UI. Unfortunately there is an ongoing issue I had to use this in docker-compose method to make it work as with swarm it works fine just had to put labels under deploy key.

Here is the Traefik service container.

```
$ cat traefik-stack.yml 
version: '3.5'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.5.4
    hostname: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=web"
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--log.filePath=/var/log/traefik.log"
      - "--accessLog.filePath=/var/log/access.log"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/log/traefik.log:/var/log/traefik.log
      - /var/log/access.log:/var/log/access.log
    networks:
      - web
    deploy:
      labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`traefik.home.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=auth"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$apr1$$s0Agr1.m$$qx8YtX13HT6oklPI7r2pO0"
      # Dummy service for Swarm port detection. The port can be any valid integer value.
      - "traefik.http.services.dummy-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9999"
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  web:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
    name: web
```

labels are showing if I use inspect on the service:

```
   "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "5dc52e7c126f7c10144a91749ac0e1ca9ab5309ea598aacfb0cf37d467f64c0d",
        "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
        "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "pihole",
        "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "docker-compose.yml",
        "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/ansible/stacks/pihole",
        "com.docker.compose.service": "pihole",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.0",
        "org.opencontainers.image.created": "2021-12-25T13:00:13.861Z",
        "org.opencontainers.image.description": "Pi-hole in a docker container",
        "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "",
        "org.opencontainers.image.revision": "b0a5a0f163804ce8e587f76b8ca508d2a9eddd59",
        "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole",
        "org.opencontainers.image.title": "docker-pi-hole",
        "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole",
        "org.opencontainers.image.version": "2021.12.1",
        "traefik.enable": "true",
        "traefik.http.middlewares.add-admin-prefix.addprefix.prefix": "/admin",
        "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.entrypoints": "web",
        "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.middlewares": "add-admin-prefix",
        "traefik.http.routers.pihole-http.rule": "Host(`pihole.home.local`)",
        "traefik.http.services.pihole-http.loadbalancer.healthcheck.scheme": "http",
        "traefik.http.services.pihole-http.loadbalancer.passhostheader": "true",
        "traefik.http.services.pihole-http.loadbalancer.server.port": "80"
    }
```

Comment: Where is the Traefik service ?

Comment: @AymDev got a point there, is your traefik service up and is it in the same docker network?

Comment: ah, I can share that too, sorry. this docker compse is not in swarm, but the traefik is running in the swarm. the docker networks is same. `web`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I can't see what's wrong here. Do you find the labels when inspecting the services ?

Comment: Yes, I can see the Labels.

Comment: Agree with AymDev ... I can't find any miss configuration too. Yet I never used docker-compose before (and mixing swarm and docker-compose is never good idea). For validation purpose, can you try to run some dummy service (whoami, etc) as swarm stack and with minimal traefik labes?

Comment: What does the traffic log states on startup? I see you have debug enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When traefik is configured with:

```
providers.docker.swarmMode=true
```

You must set the label on the swarm service, which isn't available if you deploy the container with `docker-compose`. You either need to deploy with docker-compose and the labels on the container and swarmMode set to false, or with swarmMode set to true you need to set the label in the deploy section and deploy using `docker stack deploy`, you can't mix the two configurations.

Comment: lately I stopped using this service on swarm and just using docker-compose way